# Nested docker agents in a Jenkinspipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following setup:

- Jenkinsmaster, no docker installed
- Jenkinsslave, docker is installed, label dockerslave

When I run the following pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent { node { label 'dockerslave' } } 
  stages {
    stage('Example Build') {
        agent { docker { image 'maven:3-alpine' } } 
        steps {
            echo 'Hello, Maven'
            sh 'mvn --version'
        }
    }
    stage('Example Test') {
        agent { docker { image 'openjdk:8-jre' } }
        steps {
            echo 'Hello, JDK'
            sh 'java -version'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following logoutput:

```
    [Pipeline] node
    Running on dockerslave in /home/jenkins/workspace/docker-
   declarative
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (Example Build)
    [Pipeline] node
    Still waiting to schedule task
    There are no nodes with the label ?latest?
```

The job doesn't proceed and hangs.
What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the missing:

```
reuseNode true
```

The fixed example:

```
pipeline {
  agent { 
  node { label 'dockerslave' } } 
  stages {
    stage('Example Build') {
        agent { 
            docker {
                reuseNode true 
                image 'maven:3-alpine' 
            } 
        } 
        steps {
            echo 'Hello, Maven'
            sh 'mvn --version'
        }
    }
    stage('Example Test') {
        agent { 
            docker {
                reuseNode true 
                image 'openjdk:8-jre' 
            } 
        } 
        steps {
            echo 'Hello, JDK'
            sh 'java -version'
        }
    }
  }
}
```